# How to add extra mesh with the animation

Tags: animation, rigging, parent

I have animated the dog but forgot the tongue. I have parented the tongue with empty. I want to animate the tongue with the running animation (dog) . Any suggestion how it works.

[image]

Comment: This is basic but I'll drop it here just in case you've missed something vital - I added a tongue to my 'dummy' human mesh by firstly creating the tongue and adding two bones into it, the armature and one extension so it could 'talk'.

From there (at frame 1) it was placed in the head (or mouth cavity) and parented to the head's bone by firstly (in Object mode) selecting the tongue's armature, then the human armature. Once both are highlited 'Pose' mode was used and the head bone selected. Pressing CTL-P and choosing 'Parent to Bone' from the menu finished the job.

Comment: @Edgel3D Thanks for the steps i followed. It attach to the animation few frames it work perfect when the head is raise the teeth not matching. Here how it looks https://imgur.com/gallery/5OFEyv7

Comment: If the head shape is being deformed by say more than one head-bone, that would account for the teeth misalignment.  You might be able to fix that by adjusting the head's weight painting. (see if you can reduce the mouth area's deformation) The neck-bone's influence may also be playing a part.  Again weight painting to reduce it's influence radius might help.